React Native packages compatibility
this is my package.json, have been trying to run my application but have been getting this error (image) haven't been able to resolve it. Please help.
i have upgraded multiple dependencies, even downgraded a few, it happened when i was trying to get the navigation drawer which required me to upgrade "@react-navigation/native" "@react-navigation/native-stack" did that and my app crashed downgraded it now but still the application is not working any help would be appreciated(no GPT's please)
i tried upgrading dependencies, downgrading them as well...multiple times have spent over 48 hours still unable to understand this..
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.26.0",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.26.0",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.26.3",
  "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.26.0",
  "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
  "@react-native-community/cli": "^15.1.3",
  "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.75.4",
  "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.75.4",
  "@react-native/metro-config": "0.75.4",
  "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.75.4",
  "@svgr/webpack": "^8.1.0",
  "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
  "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.6",
  "@types/react-native": "^0.73.0",
  "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
  "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
  "babel-loader": "^9.2.1",
  "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.2",
  "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.19.13",
  "eslint": "^8.57.1",
  "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.3",
  "jest": "^29.6.3",
  "prettier": "2.8.8",
  "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
  "react-test-renderer": "18.3.1",
  "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
  "typescript": "^5.0.4",
  "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
  "webpack": "^5.96.1",
  "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^5.2.0"
},

"dependencies": {
  "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.4",
  "@ionic/core": "^8.4.0",
  "@react-native-vector-icons/fontawesome": "^4.7.0",
  "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
  "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.11.0",
  "ajv": "^8.8.2",
  "ajv-keywords": "^5.1.0",
  "axios": "^1.7.7",
  "cors": "^2.8.5",
  "expo": "^52.0.17",
  "expo-font": "^13.0.1",
  "express": "^4.21.1",
  "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0",
  "react": "18.3.1",
  "react-native": "^0.75.4",
  "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.0.0",
  "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.8.0",
  "react-native-reanimated": "^2.14.4",
  "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.0.0",
  "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
  "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.2.0",
  "react-native-web": "^0.19.13",
  "react-native-web-vector-icons": "^4.4.3",
  "rimraf": "^6.0.1"
},

